# Opencart link to product in order history

Tags: php, opencart

I would like a way of having a link to the actual product ordered in the customers acount history. This used to work but since Opencart updated it no longer works

The old code is:

edit: catalog/controller/account/order.php

find:

```
$this->data['products'][] = array('order_product_id' => $product['order_product_id'],
```

add after:

```
'href' => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' .$product['order_product_id']),
```

edit: catalog/view/theme/default/template/account/order_info.php

find:

```
<?php echo $product['name']; ?>
```

replace with:

```
<a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a>
```

EDIT:: I am using version 1.5.6.4

Thanks!

Comment: Why is this not working? Any errors? Seems completely working for me...

Comment: on my website it seems to put the wrong id number and link to the wrong product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$product['product_id']` instead of `$product['order_product_id']`. Value in `order_product_id` refers to PK in table `order_product` so `product_id` is the value you want to use ;-)

Here is the `order_product` create statement for reference:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `order_product` (
  `order_product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `total` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `tax` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `reward` int(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_product_id`)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

opencart 1.5.5.1 how change on normal link?
[image]

Comment: link in administration order to edit items (admin/index.php?route=catalog/product/update&token=4d93b21563db6a6c5fe44b7c365c210b&product_id=54), this is bad, how change on normal link (index.php?route=product/product&product_id=54)